# How to change logo depending on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to accomplish is to change the logo in fixed nav when it is on another element like when I have black background to change the logo to white one and in other way.

Here is jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var scroll_start = 0;
    var startchange = $('.scroll');
    var offset = startchange.offset();
    $(document).scroll(function () {
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
      if (scroll_start > offset.top) {
        $('.logo').removeClass('logo-not-active');
        $('.logo').addClass('logo-active');
      } else if (scroll_start < offset.top) {
        $('.logo').removeClass('logo-active');
        $('.logo').addClass('logo-not-active');
      } else {
        $('.logo').removeClass('logo-active');
        $('.logo').addClass('logo-not-active');
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Don't know the relevant html, but perhaps `$(document.body).scroll...` should be the selector?

Comment: I'm not sure about that after changing it to '$(document.body).scroll' it stops working. For now it only changes on only one element, but the thing is to change it after as well

Comment: Well, then add a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we can try. You can add a fiddle-like example using the `<>` on the text area toolbar.

Comment: At the end I did solve it, below I posted the code for someone in the future. My code may be not the best but it does what I needed. Thank you Paul for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I did found a way to solve my problem but the code may not be clean or best but it does what I needed. Just for someone in future strugling to do something like this.

I just made another function.

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var mainHero = $('#hero').offset().top;
    stop = Math.round($(document).scrollTop());
    if (stop > mainHero) {
      $('.logo').removeClass('logo-not-active');
      $('.logo').addClass('logo-active');
    } else {
      $('.logo').removeClass('logo-active');
      $('.logo').addClass('logo-not-active');
    }
  });

$(document).scroll(function () {
    var mainServ = $('#services').offset().top;
    stop = Math.round($(document).scrollTop());
    if (stop > mainServ) {
      $('.logo').removeClass('logo-active');
      $('.logo').addClass('logo-not-active');
    } else {
      $('.logo').addClass('logo-active');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Element.scrollTop` property on root element to get the number of pixels that an element's content is scrolled vertically.

```js
const element = document.documentElement;
const logo = document.querySelector('#logo');

$(document).scroll(function (e) {
    
    if (element.scrollTop < 300) {
        logo.classList.remove('other');
        logo.classList.add('black');
    } else if (element.scrollTop >= 300 && element.scrollTop < 600) {
        logo.classList.remove('black');
        logo.classList.add('other');
    } else {
        logo.classList.remove('other');
        logo.classList.add('white');
    }
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
}

.p1 {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.p2 {
  background-color: #0033cc;
  color: #e066ff;
}

.p3 {
  background-color: #303030;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.inner-div {
  margin-top: 80px; 
  position: absolute;
}

#logo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.white {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.black {
  color: #000000;
}

.other {
  color: #e066ff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1 id="logo" class="black">My LOGO</h1>
<div class="p1">
<div class="inner-div">This is a div element.....</div>
</div>
<div class="p2">This is a div element.....</div>
<div class="p3">This is a div element......</div>
<div class="p3">This is a div element......</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```